# UDAF merge rows where are first orderdby in a Spark DataSet/Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

Let's say we have a `dataset`/`dataframe` in Spark where has 3 columns
`ID`, `Word`, `Timestamp`

I want to write a `UDAF` function where I can do something like this

```
df.show()

ID | Word | Timestamp
1  | I    | "2017-1-1 00:01"
1  | am   | "2017-1-1 00:02"
1  | Chris | "2017-1-1 00:03"
2  | I    | "2017-1-1 00:01"
2  | am   | "2017-1-1 00:02"
2  | Jessica | "2017-1-1 00:03"

val df_merged = df.groupBy("ID")
  .sort("ID", "Timestamp")
  .agg(custom_agg("ID", "Word", "Timestamp")

df_merged.show

ID | Words         | StartTime        |      EndTime     |
1  | "I am Chris"  | "2017-1-1 00:01" | "2017-1-1 00:03" |
1  | "I am Jessica"  | "2017-1-1 00:01" | "2017-1-1 00:03" |
```

The question is how can ensure that the column `Words` will be merged in the right order inside my `UDAF`?

Comment: The column returned from a `udaf` would always be on the end of columns in a dataframe. But you can order them anyway you want with `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sollution with Spark 2's `groupByKey` (used with an untyped `Dataset`).The advantage of groupByKey is that you have access to the group (you get an `Iterator[Row]` in `mapGroups`):

```
 df.groupByKey(r => r.getAs[Int]("ID"))
      .mapGroups{case(id,rows) => {
        val sorted = rows
          .toVector
          .map(r => (r.getAs[String]("Word"),r.getAs[java.sql.Timestamp]("Timestamp")))
          .sortBy(_._2.getTime)

        (id, 
         sorted.map(_._1).mkString(" "),
         sorted.map(_._2).head,
         sorted.map(_._2).last
         )  
        }
      }.toDF("ID","Words","StartTime","EndTime")
```

Comment: This answer is also correct.
But the groupByKey solution is a lot faster than the Window solution, at least for a small case data scenario.
Is there any particular reason?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I dont use Scala and hope you could read it.

`Window` function can do what you want:

```
df = df.withColumn('Words', f.collect_list(df['Word']).over(
    Window().partitionBy(df['ID']).orderBy('Timestamp').rowsBetween(start=Window.unboundedPreceding,
                                                                    end=Window.unboundedFollowing)))
```

Output:

```
+---+-------+-----------------+----------------+                                
| ID|   Word|        Timestamp|           Words|
+---+-------+-----------------+----------------+
|  1|      I|2017-1-1 00:01:00|  [I, am, Chris]|
|  1|     am|2017-1-1 00:02:00|  [I, am, Chris]|
|  1|  Chris|2017-1-1 00:03:00|  [I, am, Chris]|
|  2|      I|2017-1-1 00:01:00|[I, am, Jessica]|
|  2|     am|2017-1-1 00:02:00|[I, am, Jessica]|
|  2|Jessica|2017-1-1 00:03:00|[I, am, Jessica]|
+---+-------+-----------------+----------------+
```

Then `groupBy` above data:

```
df = df.groupBy(df['ID'], df['Words']).agg(
    f.min(df['Timestamp']).alias('StartTime'), f.max(df['Timestamp']).alias('EndTime'))
df = df.withColumn('Words', f.concat_ws(' ', df['Words']))
```

Output:

```
+---+------------+-----------------+-----------------+                          
| ID|       Words|        StartTime|          EndTime|
+---+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  1|  I am Chris|2017-1-1 00:01:00|2017-1-1 00:03:00|
|  2|I am Jessica|2017-1-1 00:01:00|2017-1-1 00:03:00|
+---+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: this is `python` not `scala` code, secondly perhaps you can explain the code to the OP?